# What all models/controllers are needed for building a counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter

I want to create a counter example where in the variable increments when ever the user presses a button on the webpage(view)

I have created the ruby program for the counter like this:

```
   def counter(x = 0)
     x+=1
     puts "The current value is #{x}"
   end
```

I have saved this as counter.rb. Then for the view I created another file called `counter.erb` But I dont know where to call this rb file and should I use `<%= %>` embedded ruby tags? Totally confused.

Another thing is the method counter's parameter should be linked to the `button` clicks.

Please guide me

Thanks,

Comment: Have you created a ruby app? Are you persisting a model? Have you gone through any rails tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is basic and you should be knowing this but still, I will tell you. The question is also vague so I will assume that you have a counter which is a number and a name for the counter. This is how you update any column from scratch.So first create

```
      rails generate scaffold counter count:integer name:string
```

After this step.

```
      def update
        @counter = Counter.find(params[:id])
        if @counter.update_attributes(params[:counter])
               redirect_to @counter, :flash => { :success => "Profile updated." }
        end
      end
```

After this create a view in edit.html.erb under views:

```
<%= form_for(@counter) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :count %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :count %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Go to counter.rb model and do the following:

```
class Counter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :name
end
```

You dont have to add anything in the routes file because it already has the update resource. 
Now open the browser and if you say

```
localhost:3000/counter/1/update
```

after creating the first counter value then you can update stuff from there.

This is how you updating can be done in ruby on rails. If you need more explanation regarding your code you should check the api documentation for rails it is a good start. I am a beginner too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are lacking basic understanding of Rails and MVC. I suggest you start with a simple tutorial to get a grasp on how things are working.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html will get you started with a simple app and also explains everything you need to know at the beginning.

Basically said, you need a CounterController and - if you want to persist your counter - a Counter model. or you could use a cookie.

However, I advise you to read the guide I posted above.